# LWC - Refresh Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am updating a record and want to show the updated value on the record page. I am looking to update the status field on the Case object.

My component is wrapped in a LC as it is called from a quick action (LC just passes the id to LWC and nothing more).

I am not sure if I need to return the case status to my js so I can update it with apex refresh
Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void getStatusCase(ID caseID){
    Case c = [select id, Status from case where ID =: caseID];
    c.status = 'Closed';
    update c;

    Case updatedCase = [select id, Status from case where ID =: caseID];
    return updatedCase.Status;
}
```

Everything is imported but omitted. I am unsure if I need to import the status field itself.
JS:

```
Status
connectedCallback() {
    // initialize component

    window.console.log("here in console");
    updateStatusCase({ caseID: this.recordId})
            .then(result => {
                if(result){
                    this.Status = result;
                    window.console.log("updated status: " + this.Status);
                }
                refreshApex(this.Status);
                //window.location.reload();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                window.console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });   
    }
```

I feel like there is a disconnect between the status field on the record page and the status field in my code.

Comment: The return type for `getStatusCase` should be string, not void. Also, I think updating records inside connected callback is a not good idea, it gets called every time component is refreshed.

Comment: Ah thanks. Do you know of a way to update the status field without using window.location.reload

Comment: Yes, I have updated the same in answer

Comment: Thanks. I will do what you said

Comment: please ignore the connectedcallback part of my first comment. I had jumbling between a connected and rendered call back., sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type for `getStatusCase` should be string, not void.

Also, as you are using the Aura component, you can fire one refreshView event from it. For that you need to fire one event from child LWC to parent Aura, then fire `force:refreshView` from aura handler.

In addition to the above, the following link describes how to communicate between Aura and LWC
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components